# Images not downloading in order Firebase Android

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-storage

Here's the code I'm using I want to download Images in order as I have it in my Firebase storage but it downloads randomly every time.

activity code:

```
val listAllTask: Task<ListResult> = pathReference.listAll()
      listAllTask.addOnCompleteListener{result->
          val items: List<StorageReference> = result.result!!.items
          var i = 0
          items.forEachIndexed{ _, item ->
              item.downloadUrl.addOnSuccessListener {
                  listOfAlcohols[i].images = it.toString()
                  i++
              }.addOnCompleteListener{

              }
          }
      }
```

adapter code:

```
holder.alcoholImage?.let {
        Glide.with(holder.itemView.context).load(mDataList[position].images).override(200,200).into(
            it
        )
    }
```

Comment: do you have no way of sorting these images yourself ? perhaps giving them names they can be sorted on would help

Comment: I did but the problem is happening when it's downloading. I have the images url in order but when it's showing in the recyclerview after downloading it's not in order.

Comment: but my point remains, sort them till they are in order ?

Comment: thanks man! sorting the array did it. A stupid mistake on my end.